# How to control print font size

Tags: javascript, css, printing, media-queries, font-size

I am allowing my users to print but the output is way too large (I have to manually adjust to about 60% in the print dialog). I use a css media query (below) to control the content and have tried changing the font-size of the `html, body{}`without any change to the output font size. Printing to Adobe PDF prints correctly

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

My Print Link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;"></a>
```

My css:

```
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .printme, .printme * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .printme {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .printme, .printme:last-child {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }

    .display-none-on, .display-none-on * {
        display: none !important;
    }
    html, body {
        height: auto;
        font-size: 12pt; /* changing to 10pt has no impact */
    }

}
```

Comment: These code works... I think the problem is the cache.. Try to open in private mode browser..

Comment: Because the CSS only works for print? Not when viewed on screen?

Comment: I am using Firefox, but tried printing in Chrome with the same result.

Comment: If you have external CSS, which you should, it will be saved in your cache. Clear your cache. Firefox can be set up to do this when you close your Browser.

Comment: @PHPglue Clearing the cache worked. I set the css back to the original 12pt size and all is good. How come the print font size got out of wack to begin with?

Comment: The cache stores CSS and JavaScript the way it was last loaded into the Browser. If it recognizes the file, it just pulls from memory instead of loading recent info. This speeds up code load time the next time a user visits your site.

Comment: Yes, but I wonder where it pulled the jumbo font size from.I haven't been playing with css font size at all, otherwise I would have thought cache right away. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For me it was !important use on font size on global css file. So having font-size:12pt !mportant made the trick.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally figured this out and there were multiple causes. The main thing is that I needed to also set the font-size for the div that contained the text. In the main css, I have body font-size set to 62.5% and the div font-size set to 130%. When I set the body font-size for @media print{} to 12pt, it continued to use the 130% div setting and so printed very large.

I believe my efforts to adjust the font-size via changing the body font-size were flawed because I minify my css and probably forgot to minify after each change.

Comment: Why  it continued to use the 130% div setting?

Comment: @Alex78191 - The page will use the div font size (which was set to 130%) even when body font-size is changed. When I changed the div font size originally in the CSS file, I didn't remember to minify the css when testing and so my changes did not take effect.

Comment: I marked with upvote because your explanation help me a lot in my problem.